# Can I provide the username to use in a SAML request? (AD FS)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, adfs

When initiating a SAML authentication request (from the Service Provider), is there any way to give the Identity Provider a hint as to which username to use?  In my application I know which user it wants to authenticate (based on a unique link the user clicked in an e-mail), and I'd like that username to be prefilled in the IdP's username box.

Using SAML 2.0 with Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS) 2.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can use the optional `<saml:Subject>` field in the `AuthnRequest` message sent from the SP to the Idp to request a specific subject from the Idp. See section 3.4.1 in the [SAML2 spec](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35711/sstc-saml-core-errata-2.0-wd-06-diff.pdf).

I have no idea if ADFS respects that field though.

Comment: AD FS 2.0 did not appear to honor that in the request.  Hopefully support for that is added someday!